# Tex Live Utility: "Listing Failed"

Tags: texlive, mac, mactex

As of yesterday, TeX Live Utility is telling me "Listing Failed" anytime I try to perform updates, or even look at any packages/backups of packages on my machine.

It was working perfectly fine two days ago. Here is information from the log files.

```
2013-09-15 21:20:39 +0000 Notice -[TLMOperation main][434]  Failed executing `/usr/texbin/tlmgr --machine-readable --repository http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet/ update --list --all` (error 25)
2013-09-15 21:20:39 +0000 Notice -[TLMOperation main][434]  Unknown docfile tag:  texmf-dist/doc/latex/pythontex/pythontex_quickstart.pdf details=""Quick start" documentation" at /usr/local/texlive/2013/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm line 127, <TMP> line 129108.
```

Other potentially relevant information: I'm running Mac OS X 10.8.5 and TeX Live Utility Version 1.13 (both the most recent versions of each, I believe).

Reinstalling TeX Live Manager from the `Actions` menu of TeX Live Utility did not do solve the problem.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be based on the log files? Any help in troubleshooting this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @egreg That fixed 2 of 3 problems. I can do updates and look at backups now. However, when I try to look at the packages installed on my machine, Tex Live Utility just hangs. This might be a separate issue. I'm not sure. The log says `2013-09-15 21:53:13 +0000 Notice -[TLMMainWindowController _refreshFullPackageListFromLocation:offline:][1044] Refreshing list of all packages…`, and it's just been hanging like that for the last 20 minutes.

Comment: I'm afraid this is caused by the mismatch that's created between the `texlive.tlpdb` files, local and remote.

Comment: @egreg Fair enough, I'll wait a few days and see if it goes away. If nothing else, maybe I'll just try a complete reinstall or something. You can close this as a duplicate, if you'd like, or should I just delete it?

Comment: @egreg I just noticed that in `usr/local/texlive/2013/tlpkg` I have 9 different files that look something like `texlive.tlpdb.0aa966d6fd66fd38361241c0f0eb55de` in addition to `texlive.tlpdb`. Should those be there?